# Use lattice on part of object

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a simple chair, and I want one of the back legs to be curved/bended. I tried using a lattice for this, with a vertex group set to the vertices in the leg. But the result is super-weird as you can hopefully see in the picture.
[image: Strange Lattice Result]
The vertex group (RightBendyLeg) can be seen selected in yellow.
I don't understand why the leg grows on the z-axis, as I would think the lattice has almost the same size on the z-axis as the leg. Can someone explain this behaviour?
If I wanted to created a bend/curved leg like this, is there a better way than using a lattice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can stem from applying scale to the lattice. You shouldn't do it. Apply scale to a chair, create new lattice for the leg and don't apply scale to it. Then this setup should work perfectly, but I would suggest to subdivide the leg little more to get the effect, you need. 
Also in my opinion it would be easier to just use proportional editing directly on the leg vertices to get desired curvature. Lattice doesn't give more control in this particular example.
I would also suggest you to split the chair on 2 and use mirror modifier to ensure, that bending will be exactly the same for both legs.

Comment: Totally agree with everything you wrote. And I want to underline that this is really not case where lattice can be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. You're probably right about the proportional editing. I just wanted to get this as well. And another thing I think I did wrong was I matched up the lattice in edit-mode instead of in object-mode.

Comment: This indeed seems like an applied scale problem. It's debatable question if lattice give little control here, because it's non-destructive editing. You can bend it with Curve modifier which could point to any curve you like (or use Curve modifier on the object itself).

Comment: There is plenty of options to make shape change non-destructive (like f.ex. shape key) so in my opinion using lattice or curve modifier to change a shape of a leg in such a simple chair would be an excess of form over substance